# Java 2D drawString boxes instead chinese characters

Tags: java, java-2d, chinese-locale

Server is CentOS.

```
[root@CentOS-73-64-minimal ~]# fc-list : family
```

- Clean
- Lohit Kannada
- PT Sans
- Carlito
- Khmer OS System
- Lohit Nepali
- Meera
- PT Sans Narrow
- DejaVu Sans Mono
- Nuosu SIL
- Khmer OS Content
- Open Sans,Open Sans Semibold
- Lohit Oriya
- PakType Naskh Basic
- FreeSerif
- Lohit Assamese
- Padauk
- DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Light
- WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬微米黑,文泉驿等宽微米黑
- DejaVu Sans
- VL Gothic,VL ゴシック
- DejaVu Serif,DejaVu Serif Condensed
- Lohit Punjabi
- NanumGothic,나눔고딕
- DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Condensed
- Khmer OS
- Open Sans
- Liberation Mono
- WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono,文泉驛等寬正黑,文泉驿等宽正黑
- Madan
- Caladea
- AR PL UMing TW MBE
- NanumGothic,나눔고딕,NanumGothicExtraBold,나눔고딕 ExtraBold
- WenQuanYi Micro Hei,文泉驛微米黑,文泉驿微米黑
- AR PL UMing HK
- Lohit Telugu
- AR PL UMing CN
- AR PL UMing TW
- Lohit Marathi
- Lohit Gujarati
- Liberation Serif
- Lohit Malayalam
- STIX
- LKLUG
- WenQuanYi Zen Hei Sharp,文泉驛點陣正黑,文泉驿点阵正黑
- Liberation Sans
- Jomolhari
- WenQuanYi Zen Hei,文泉驛正黑,文泉驿正黑
- FreeSans
- Fixed
- Lohit Devanagari
- Lohit Tamil
- Lohit Bengali
- Abyssinica SIL
- Waree
- Open Sans,Open Sans Light
- Overpass
- DejaVu Serif
- Open Sans,Open Sans Extrabold
- FreeMono
- Amiri

When I draw string with Chinese Characters, java draws boxes

[image: box]

Here is the code:

```
         Font font = new Font("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12);
                context2d.setFont(font);
                color(color);
                context2d.drawString(text, x, y);
```

The result should be:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Added Chinese fonts?

Comment: sure, please look at fc-list

Answer (score 0):

This code works excellent!

```
Font font = new Font("Open Sans, Lucida Sans", Font.PLAIN, 12);
                context2d.setFont(font);
                color(color);
                context2d.drawString(text, x, y);
```